# Two interconnected if statements coming up with the wrong answer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using two if statements to work out which threshold to use for a calculation. The problem I'm having is it's not working as the code says it should I'm using the first if statement to work out month which is:

`=IF(AND(MONTH(TODAY()) >=X2, MONTH(TODAY()) <=X3), "75", "50")`

That works fine. The cell next to it has the following formula and it's not changing answer at all.

`=IF(T2>=W5, "Yes", "No")`

X2 was set at 4 and X3 was 8, T2 was the score I've tried from 49, 50 and 51 it doesn't change at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: What is `T2` and what is `W5` in this scenario. Is that first formula in one of those two cells? My best guess though is to remove the quotation marks around your numbers in your first `IF()` formula. Perhaps you are comparing numbers to strings in your second?

Comment: T2 is the total of rows so that's a simple ```=SUM(E2:S2)``` and W5 is the first IF statement. I've tried removing the quotation marks and it just sticks of Yes even if that's incorrect

Comment: Just got it working, I'd made an error with one of the numbers and so your fix worked perfectly. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because in your first statement, 75 and 50 are in quotes, which makes excel understand them as strings. Remove the quotes from the first if statement and it should work as expected.